# Emacs auto-complete popup menu broken

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

I'm have reinstalled my emacs and now I'm using emacs v24.3.50 with `auto-complete` v1.4 and `popup.el` v0.5. Unfortunately the popup "menu" of auto-complete is kinda broken (see attached screenshot).
The different items are not aligned along a commong vertical line [ignore the black overlay, that stems from CEDET and is probably meant to be placed on the right side next to the popup menu; the problem remains when disabling CEDET, so it is not related).

[image: example of error]

From what I can tell it looks like the extent of this "shift" between lines depends on how much the length of the strings differs. Also, when selecting a different suggestion using the arrow keys the horizontal shift of the lines changes a little (~few pixels) each time the mark is moved one line up/down.

I have uploaded the part of my `.emacs.d/init.el` that is used for configuring auto-complete [here](http://pastebin.com/jR0U4kcD).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears you are using a proportional font, which breaks the calculation of the left edge of the overlay.

You can try changing the way auto-complete computes the column:

```
(setq popup-use-optimized-column-computation nil)
```

You can also change to a fixed width font.

Note that some other completion systems for Emacs can use tooltips instead of overlays, which would avoid this problem.

Comment: Setting that variable didn't work but switching to a fixed-width font did the trick (I'm now using `Inconsolata`; didn't know that the font I used was not fixed-width). Thanks!